# Can't install vagrant-hostsupdater

Tags: ruby, rubygems, vagrant, installation

I try to fire vagrant up for VVV, but it has a local plugin dependency, the vagrant-hostsupdater. When I say yes to install it while vagrant starts up, I get this error message:

```
vagrant-hostsupdater
Install local plugins (Y/N) [N]: Y
Installing the 'vagrant-hostsupdater' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/win32/registry.rb:652:in encode': incomplete "\x00" on UTF-16LE (Encoding::InvalidByteSequenceError) from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/win32/registry.rb:652:in read'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/win32/resolv.rb:67:in read_s' from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/win32/resolv.rb:119:in block (5 levels) in get_info'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/win32/resolv.rb:117:in each' from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/win32/resolv.rb:117:in find'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/win32/resolv.rb:117:in block (4 levels) in get_info' from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/win32/registry.rb:435:in open'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/win32/registry.rb:542:in open' from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/win32/resolv.rb:116:in block (3 levels) in get_info'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/win32/registry.rb:612:in each_key' from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/win32/resolv.rb:115:in block (2 levels) in get_info'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/win32/registry.rb:435:in open' from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/win32/registry.rb:542:in open'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/win32/resolv.rb:114:in block in get_info' from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/win32/registry.rb:435:in open'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/win32/registry.rb:542:in open' from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/win32/resolv.rb:91:in get_info'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/win32/resolv.rb:21:in get_resolv_info' from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/resolv.rb:1002:in default_config_hash'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/resolv.rb:1019:in block in lazy_initialize' from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/resolv.rb:1012:in synchronize'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/resolv.rb:1012:in lazy_initialize' from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/resolv.rb:358:in block in lazy_initialize'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/resolv.rb:356:in synchronize' from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/resolv.rb:356:in lazy_initialize'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/resolv.rb:516:in fetch_resource' from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/resolv.rb:510:in each_resource'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/resolv.rb:491:in getresource' from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:105:in api_endpoint'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/source.rb:47:in api_uri' from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/source.rb:183:in load_specs'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.4/gems/vagrant-2.2.4/lib/vagrant/bundler.rb:429:in block in validate_configured_sources!' from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/source_list.rb:98:in each'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/source_list.rb:98:in each_source' from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.4/gems/vagrant-2.2.4/lib/vagrant/bundler.rb:427:in validate_configured_sources!'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.4/gems/vagrant-2.2.4/lib/vagrant/bundler.rb:335:in internal_install' from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.4/gems/vagrant-2.2.4/lib/vagrant/bundler.rb:133:in install'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.4/gems/vagrant-2.2.4/lib/vagrant/plugin/manager.rb:138:in block in install_plugin' from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.4/gems/vagrant-2.2.4/lib/vagrant/plugin/manager.rb:148:in install_plugin'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.4/gems/vagrant-2.2.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:972:in block in process_configured_plugins' from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.4/gems/vagrant-2.2.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:963:in each'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.4/gems/vagrant-2.2.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:963:in process_configured_plugins' from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.4/gems/vagrant-2.2.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:179:in initialize'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.4/gems/vagrant-2.2.4/bin/vagrant:145:in new' from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.4/gems/vagrant-2.2.4/bin/vagrant:145:in

'
```

I checked the spelling, but it its correct. I removed vagrant from my system and installed it again. No change. It seems to be a problem with the ruby gems install. I am clueless...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to answer it myself: There is a problem with the hostsupdater on Windows 10. With a fresh version and clean install everything works as aspected. To make it really work everything from Ruby to Vagrant to VVV has to be reinstalled with the newest versions.

On MacOS everything works out of the box.